# After remove button is clicked would like the checkbox to go unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am trying to have my checkbox unchecked after someone confirms the removal of the items. Would like to know how I go about doing so? Hope someone can help me with this.

Here is my code:

JS:

```
$(".rem-btn").click(function(){
        var remConf = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove these items from your shopping list?");
        if (remConf == true) {
            $(".check-list input:checked").not('#select-all').parent().remove();
        };
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="shop-list">
            <div class="add-item">
                <input id="item-add" type='text' placeholder="Enter item to shopping list..." name="itemAdd"></input>
                <button class="add-btn">Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <div class="item-list">
                <h2>Shopping List</h2>              
                <ul class="check-list">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"/>Select All</li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
            <div class="removal">
                <button class="rem-btn">Remove Selected</button>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: CAn you present your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prop` to uncheck the checkbox : `$("#select-all").prop("checked",false);` You can define any selector you need.

```js
$(".rem-btn").click(function(){
        var remConf = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove these items from your shopping list?");
        if (remConf == true) {
            $(".check-list input:checked").not('#select-all').parent().remove();
          $("#select-all").prop("checked",false);
        };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="shop-list">
            <div class="add-item">
                <input id="item-add" type='text' placeholder="Enter item to shopping list..." name="itemAdd"></input>
                <button class="add-btn">Add Item</button>
            </div>
            <div class="item-list">
                <h2>Shopping List</h2>              
                <ul class="check-list">
                    <li><input type="checkbox" id="select-all"/>Select All</li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
            <div class="removal">
                <button class="rem-btn">Remove Selected</button>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks for the help it definitely worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".rem-btn").click(function () {
    var remConf = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove these items from your shopping list?");
    if (remConf == true) {
        console.log('qeqw');
        $(".check-list input:checked").attr('checked',false);
    };
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltpey8qo/)

Use `attr` checked and set it to false or use `prop`

Comment: Since checbox value is addressed here, it is better to use prop, Where both a property and an attribute with the same name exists, usually updating one will update the other, but this is not the case for certain attributes of inputs, such as value and checked: for these attributes, the property always represents the current state while the attribute (except in old versions of IE) corresponds to the default value/checkedness of the input (reflected in the defaultValue / defaultChecked property).

Comment: @KAD very informative i will keep that in mind. use prop for checkbox and radio button.